# building a cryptocurrency investment website using react, html javascript and css

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, deployment, frontend

i am a beginner to web development. i want to work on a project which is a cryptocurrency investment website that has the following features :
1 a landing page showing the different packages to choose from, footer, navbar and other things
2 A contact us page
3 an about us page
4 a sign up section
5 a dashboard that shows you all of your earnings and details.
6 beautiful and appealing ui

i need details on the best way i can go about this and useful technologies i can use to achieve this. i have no knowledge of back end and i assume its needed. maybe firebase can be used for that.
where can i get a free already coded template that matches these features so i can just edit and customise to my own. i won't be able to code everything from scratch as it would be very tedious and time consuming. anything that would be helpful to complete this project would be deeply appreciated

i tried searching online for templates from fresestheme but the ones i saw need to be paid for. i tried coding everything from scratch but it is too tedious and time consuming. i eventually gave up on that.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.